# Paypal single payout issue for non US citizen

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are developing a steam website in which steam users can login and sell their skins to us. For merchant steam account(from which tradeoffer will be sent to steam users and their skins will come in this account) firstly we were using only email authentication for login process(script - https://github.com/SzymonLisowiec/php-steamlogin) in order to get the cookies and send tradeoffer to steam users using curl. But we have to sell this all steam users skins(which are in our merchant account) to another website name skin.cash so we enabled mobile authentication into our merchant account so skins would exchange immediately, by enabling this feature the trading process for users is a bit changed , now this script(https://github.com/SzymonLisowiec/php-steamlogin) always ask for two factor code. So we inputted once and saved those cookies and session id into database and used them to send tradeoffer to steam users.But at some point or after some days those cookies are getting expire.

Do all other steam bot present in market only use email authentication for merchant account ???

Or is there any other solution or script for this???

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming in any way, shape or form ....

Comment: I got an error when i moved from sandbox to live , it says '' AUTHENTICATION ERROR'' in single payout service of paypal